# Fancytree JSON CSS class for icon

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I am trying to use CSS classes for icons instead of the icon property

so instead of having

```
{icon : "public/assets/icon.gif" } ;
```

to have something like

```
{icon : className} ;
```

If this possible ? If not , is it something i can do with jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `icon` property, like you are doing right now.

From the [documentation](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/global.html#NodeData):

> boolean | string  icon
>   Define this node's icon. undefined: Use global
>   tree option of the same name true: Use default icon, depending on
>   `node.folder` and `node.expanded` status false: Hide icon String: A
>   string value that contains a '/' or a '.' is used as `src` attribute
>   for a  tag. (See also the global `imagePath` option.) **Any other
>   string value is used to generate custom tags, e.g. for "ui-icon
>   ui-icon-heart": .**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to change image from CSS, Try this

```
.icon:before{
   content: url(public/assets/icon.gif);
}


{icon : 'icon'}
```

Comment: I think you mean: .icon:before{
   content: url("public/assets/icon.gif");
}


{icon : 'icon'}

Comment: {icon: icon} seems to break the JSON , it neds {icon: 'icon'} but works , thanks